# i commit my code and all is lost how can i bring them back?

Tags: git

I don't know how to use git. I was trying to push the codes. I chose from vscode and pressed commit, the changes were gone, then I accidentally checked out and all the changes I made are gone. Where can I find the codes that I last committed but did not push? Is there a way to bring them back?

Comment: What did you checkout? A branch? Another commit hash? Your changes probably still exist, but just not where you're currently looking.

Answer (score 2):

> Where can I find the codes that I last committed but did not push? Is there a way to bring them back?

Absolutely! Everything you have committed is still there, because
commits are not deleted. That's the whole point of Git. So just look
through the reflog for the commit that you want. Say

```
git reflog --all
```

However, it is likely that there is nothing to worry about. Having things change drastically when you checkout something is expected behavior. That is what checkout *means*.

Comment: Since you say you don't know Git, why not get to know it before playing around with it? Here's my intro: https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/